# How to protect from chrooting to its linux partition and how to chroot it after using the protection?

Tags: security, chroot

I am currently using archlinux,
It is possible to boot on an archlinux installation iso for instance, to mount my current archlinux partition and my boot partition and then to use arch-chroot. Then I have access to a root shell in my archlinux system and I can for example install, uninstall things, change root passwd ...

The question is : How to protect from such a manipulation that doesnt require the root passwd to access a root shell ?

I think that there is something to do with disk encrytion.

Assuming that I protected my archlinux partition from chrooting, how does it work if I need to chroot into it ? I usually only do
mount /dev/sdax /mnt
mount /dev/sday /mnt/boot
arch-chroot /mnt

Thank you !

Comment: You have to prevent physical access. Short of that, perform an encrypted install.

Comment: Ok but how does it work if I want to chroot into my system ? Is there a command asking for my root password to uncrypt the install ?

Comment: Yes -  there are any number of tutorial on how to do this. Covered here - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Change_root

Answer (score 1):

The problem is more general than the case described and isn't specific to chroot, archlinux or linux.

In the general case, if an attacker has physical access to the system, they can read/modify any data stored on the disk, whether by physical means (removing the disk and mounting it on their own machine, possibly replacing it afterward) or through software (boot into their own OS and read/modify data without restriction as described in the original question).

As you hinted, a possible countermeasure against this would be to utilize encryption.  This prevents an attacker who doesn't have the key (file, smartcard, password, etc.) from meaningfully reading or modifying data.

An attacker who encounters an encrypted system and is unable to recover the key can read the encrypted data (looks random) and write data which is unlikely to be decrypted meaningfully (equivalent of writing random bits to your HDD).  They could corrupt/destroy data by doing so, but otherwise shouldn't be able to install/uninstall programs or change passwords.

In the case of full system encryption, the decryption key is required at boot time.  Once the system is unlocked, then you can chroot as usual (assuming you have the correct privileges).

The way that this protects you is that you need the key in order to make meaningful read/writes of data and once the key has been inputted and the system booted, the OS's security measures (user authentication, permissions, ACLs, etc.) should kick in to control access.

Comment: Do you mean there is an extra password before login in with any user account ? Is it possible that when you log in your account, it only decrypts what your account can access (and not an extra password at every boot)